# I'm trying to create a simple login and sign up screen for an application I'm developing. I want to use a dictionary to s

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to create a simple login and sign up screen in swift for an application I'm developing. I want to use a dictionary to store the multiple usernames and passwords that are later checked by a conditional, to see if the key matches the value, to login. The main issue I'm running into is the placement of the dictionary where it can be used by both login view controller and sign up view controller. Currently, I made the login VC a subclass of the  sign up VC; however, the login screen isn't receiving the dictionary from the sign up screen. What can I do to inherit this dictionary from one VC to another, or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: This question can be answered in one word `Protocol` google it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's a subclass, and it has all the variables that the superclass does, they are not the same variables.  You have two different objects of different classes. Making it a subclass doesn't buy you anything in this direction, and makes your code more confusing.  There are two general strategies for this:  1) allocate the dictionary in a third object that both objects have a reference to, or 2) when you create your second object, give it a property of the first object type, and write the first object into it.

// rough code follows in obj C

```
Class signin:

@interface SignIn: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary * dict;

@end

Class Login:

@class SignIn;

@interface Login: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) SignIn * mySigninController;

@end

@implementation Signin

...
// create login controller

self.myLoginController = [[Login alloc] init];

// add the reference to myself in login

self.myLoginController.mySigninController = self;

...

in login:

...

my value = self.mySigninController.dict[@"key"];
```